# How can I reset the MUI autocomplete when changing the value in another autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have 2 MUI autocompletes. When the user changes the materialCategoryValue in the MaterialCategoryPicker, the other autocomplete, the MaterialPicker has to reset. I've tried many solutions(I added a useEffect) but nothing has worked. It has to be an easy fix but I cannot see how to solve the issue. I'm passin the value and the onChange as props from the parent to the children.
I'm using a reducer where I set material to be undefined.
MaterialPicker

```
const MATERIAL_OPTIONS: Array<Material> = [
  mockMaterial(),
  mockMaterial(),
  mockMaterial(),
  mockMaterial(),
];

interface MaterialPickerProps {
  value: CustomMaterial | Material | undefined;
  materialCategoryValue: MaterialCategory | undefined;
  isCustomAllowed: boolean;
  onChange: (newMaterial: CustomMaterial | Material | undefined) => void;
}

const MaterialPicker = ({
  value,
  materialCategoryValue,
  onChange,
}: MaterialPickerProps): ReactElement => {
  const { palette } = useTheme();

  const [autocompleteOpen, setAutocompleteOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [_, setAnchorEl] = useState<Element & EventTarget | null>(null);
  const [hasHover, setHasHover] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [hasFocus, setHasFocus] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const isValueValid = true;

  const error = useMemo((): { message: string } | undefined =>
     undefined
  , []);

  const handleMouseEnter = useCallback((): void => void setHasHover(true), []);

  const handleMouseLeave = useCallback((): void => void setHasHover(false), []);

useEffect(() => {
  // Reset Autocomplete value and close the dropdown when material category changes
  if (!materialCategoryValue) {
    onChange(undefined);
    setAutocompleteOpen(false);
  }
}, [materialCategoryValue, onChange]);

  return (
    // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-no-useless-fragment
    <>
      <InvalidTooltip
        title={error?.message}
        open={!hasFocus && hasHover && !!error}
      >
        <Autocomplete<CustomMaterial | Material | undefined>
          sx={{
            width: 1,
            [`& .${autocompleteClasses.inputRoot}`]: {
              marginTop: '0 !important',
              height: '100% !important',
              paddingLeft: 5,
            },
            [`& .${autocompleteClasses.endAdornment}`]: {
              right: 16,
            },
            ...materialCategoryValue && (hasHover || !isValueValid) ? {
              outline: `2px solid ${palette[isValueValid ? 'primary' : 'error'].main}`,
              zIndex: 999,
            } : {},
          }}
          options={MATERIAL_OPTIONS}
          disabled={!materialCategoryValue}
          value={value}
          renderInput={(props: AutocompleteRenderInputParams): JSX.Element => (
            <TextField
              {...props}
              defaultValue={value}
              inputProps={{
                ...props.inputProps,
                // Enables searching the autocomplete
                readOnly: false,
              }}
              placeholder={!materialCategoryValue ? 'Category required' : 'Select material'}
              InputProps={{
                ...props.InputProps,
                disableUnderline: true,
              }}
              sx={{
                height: INPUT_HEIGHT,
              }}
            />
          )}
          getOptionLabel={(material): string => material?.compositions ? getCompositionLabel(material.compositions) : ''}
          open={autocompleteOpen}
          blurOnSelect
          onKeyDown={(event): void => {
            if (event.key === 'Enter') {
              setAutocompleteOpen(true);
            }
          }}
          onFocus={(): void => void setHasFocus(true)}
          onBlur={(): void => {
            setHasFocus(false);
          }}
          onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
          onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
          onOpen={(e): void => {
            setAnchorEl(e.currentTarget);
            setAutocompleteOpen(true);
          }}
          // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-shadow
          onChange={(_, newMaterial): void => {
              onChange(newMaterial ?? undefined);
          }}
          onClose={(): void => {
            setAutocompleteOpen(false);
            setAnchorEl(null);
          }}
        />
      </InvalidTooltip>
    </>
  );
};
```

Reducer

```
const extendedCompositionReducer = (
  state: ExtendedCompositionState,
  action: ExtendedCompositionAction,
): ExtendedCompositionState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'select_material':
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.targetUsage]: {
          ...state[action.payload.targetUsage],
          material: action.payload.material,
        },
      };
    case 'select_material_category':
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload.targetUsage]: {
          ...state[action.payload.targetUsage],
          materialCategory: action.payload.materialCategory,
          material: undefined,
        },
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```